# Android SDK API offline documentation does not work on android studio , All Packages are not available for download

Tags: android, android-studio, document

**Hi,**
I downloaded android studio and installed it downloaded API 30.0.1

but when I press Ctrl+Q to show inline docs, android studio try to fetch it from the network `online`

[image]

[image]
I need it to work offline, I can not find the old option in the SDK manager

`Documentation for Android SDK`

[image]

And when I try to navigate to any class or method in android API `navigate to source Ctrl + L-mouse-button`

android studio show me

[image: first message]

and when I press on download option `in the top right corner`

it shows me

[image]

And This is My SDK Manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

The Project

And build.gradle `Module`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.albanna.databaseworks"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

build.gradle `Project`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### My SDK Folder

[image: d]

#### My Laptop Configurations

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

BIOS Mode   UEFI

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB, dual-channel 2666 MHz

SSD NVME M2 3200/2500 read/write MB/S
```

---

So I need it to work like IntelliJ IDE or Rider, when I press Ctrl+Q on any method, it should show the docs and I can navigate to the source `Offline`

#### Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## I Found The Solution

This problem because Google does not provide the source code of API 30 yet, so
I just go back to API 29, and everything work

from `File` → `Project Structure` → `Modules`

then change

- `Compile Sdk Version` to `29`
- `Build Tools Version` `29.0.3`

Also notice: you must have `Source For Android 29` or any version you have, selected
in  `SDK Platforms`

[image]

I notice this problem from [this thread on readit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d0csjt/tired_of_looking_sources_for_android_api_29/ezab0p6/)

And this says that Google will only release the source with the system, not with the API.

So I just go back to API 29