# Android Studio 4.0 Documentation Pop-Up Is Not Working Properly

Tags: android, android-studio, popup, documentation, android-studio-4.0

While I'm reviewing codes online of old versions of Android Studio, I see more attributes of a function than I see in my own version.

[Old Version pop-up like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg9rj.png)

When I try to see attributes of an object:

[My Android Studio 4.0 pop-up like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yElao.png)

I checked a lot of answers but no one talks about version 4.0

In most of answers people talk about downloading "Documentation for Android Studio" from Android SDK. There is nothing about this on Version 4.0. I cannot download "Documentation for Android Studio"

[Android Studio 4.0 Settings of Android SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy51d.png)

Here is an old version of Android Studio and you can see the section.

[An old version of Android Studio Settings of Android SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVEBP.png)

- I already tried to change documentation location from *jdk.table.xml*
- I already tried `Android Studio -> Preference -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Show the documentation popup`

I want to learn how I can reach more attributes of a function in Android Studio 4.0 and use the functions properly.

Comment: Here is 3 answers I got from Google Android Developer Team but non of my answers. It may be yours:

"The latest Android reference docs are available online, and they include every overload of each function."

"We no longer provide downloadable SDK documentation through Android Studio 4.0."

"If you enable the Code Completion parameter popup, they can see all the information they're looking for in Android Studio 4.0.
To do so in Android Studio go to File > Settings > Search "popup" > click Code Completion > select "Show the documentation popup" and select "Show the parameter info popup"

Answer (score 2):

You need to go and download the sources for the API you want. I wasn't sure but I just deleted the sources and now it shows like yours. Download them and you'll be fine. Got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925522/8228163.

That offline documentation they must be talking about the "See on C" or something like that. Interesting to know it's now only online, so thanks haha.